# Extract header from wav file in php (especially duration and timecode)

Tags: php, audio, header, unpack

I want to find out the duration and starttime (timecode) of a wav file with php. I'm trying this but all that I get returned are zeroes. Ideas?

1)

```
<pre>
<?php
$fp = fopen('wav.wav', 'r');
fseek($fp, 20);
$rawheader = fread($fp, 16);
$header = unpack('vtype/vchannels/Vsamplerate/Vbytespersec/valignment/vbits',
$rawheader);
print_r($header);
?>
</pre>
```

Returns

```
Array (
[type] => 0
[channels] => 0
[samplerate] => 0
[bytespersec] => 0
[alignment] => 0
[bits] => 0 )
```

And two more questions:

2) what do I need to put in unpack to find out the duration and starttime?

3) Can I do this on a wav file on a separate server, and, will the whole file be downloaded or does it just open the headers quickly to extract what's needed?

Comment: May wanna take a look at https://github.com/JamesHeinrich/getID3 library.

Comment: @Hexchaimen Thanks, that looks pretty powerful. I see the duration, do you happen to know if it can/how to extract the timestamp (timecode), which is embedded somewhere in wav files? Also if I understand it correctly, if I run this on an audio file on a different server, the file need to be copied locally first?

Comment: Correct, the file needs to be local.  The header of the WAV (usually 44bytes) has most the info needed to find all you're looking for.  I would refer to this: http://www.topherlee.com/software/pcm-tut-wavformat.html

Comment: The file doesn't have to be local. You can rewrite this with file_get_contents or cURL and get the raw contents and check that. `$fp = file_get_contents("http://url.tld/file.wav");
$rawheader = substr($fp,20,16);
$header = unpack('vtype/vchannels/Vsamplerate/Vbytespersec/valignment/vbits',$rawheader);
print_r($header);`